# Chat rooms on java serversocket

Tags: java, hashmap, chat, serversocket

Could you please help me?

I try to make chat rooms in a chat on java using ServerSocket. I have 2 hashmaps there.

```
private HashMap<String, UserThread> userMap = new HashMap<>(); // **username and thread**
private HashMap<String, String> chatRooms = new HashMap<>(); //  **username and room name**
```

```
 public void sendMessage(String message, UserThread excludeUser) {
        for (UserThread aUser : userMap.values()){
            if (aUser != excludeUser) {
                aUser.sendMessage(message);
            }
        }

    }
```

During the registration, the client enters his username and room name.
The first hashmap has usernames and appropriate threads. The second one has usernames and room names.
I have a method that sends messages to all users.

Can you advise how to make a method that will help me to compare chat room names and send messages to those clients (UserThread) who are in the same room?

Comment: Please read: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: You need to find or create a protocol that will help you send messages that contain the room and other information you need.